# Which of following is a subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question is todetermine which of following is subgroup of G question stated as

[image]

I have to check condition $AB^{-1} $ , whether it belongs to H or not , butwhen i check that $Ab^{-1} $ is equal to I in both cases , I being identity matrix , so is it safe to say both are subgroups of G

Comment: Please, take a look at this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to use MathJax.

Comment: @AaronMaroja i shall surely do that , exams very near and my typing is very slow so posting pictures .

Comment: What conditions must be satisfied in order to a set be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja the condition is recalled in the post already.

Comment: $AB^{-1} $= Iin both cases

Comment: @quid I didn't read.

Comment: I can't see any difference between $H_1$ and $H_2$!

Comment: I didn't notice, before I posted my answer, that $\;H_1\;,\;\;H_2\;$ seem to be *exactly* the same set...am I missing something? This is either a mistake or something misterious is going on here.

Comment: They state answer B

Comment: Probably the $c$ in $H_2$ is meant to be at the bottom left, but who knows?

Comment: You need to be careful when doing the check. In the description of $H_1$ you have a parameter $b$, this $b$ is not the same for $A$ and $B$. Use a $b_1$ for $A$ and $b_2$ for $B$ and you will get a different outcome.

Comment: @timbuc THERE IS A TYPO . IN H2 there is 1 instead of 2

Comment: @godonichia As Derek and I noticed: what is the difference between $\;H_1\,,\,\,H_2\;$ ? None!

Comment: If you just want to answer the question quickly, you could also note that the identity matrix is not in the subset and it thus cannot be a subgroup.

Comment: Ok @godonichia . Quid's comment is the fastest answer possible, and with the correction $\;H_2\;$ is a subgroup. Check this now.

Comment: If you replace the $2$ in $H_2$ by $1$, then it is a subgroup, but you need to prove it.

Comment: @DerekHolt I would guess as the answerkey seems to say the answer is B that 2 for $H_2$ is 1. (Sorry did not see you latetest comment; seems we agree)

Comment: @DerekHolt In H2 , now AB^(-1) belongs to H2 , but do i haveto checkall 4 axioms along with this

Comment: @godonichia No, you don't have to... **if** you already proved elsewhere that a *non-empty* subset of a group is a subgroup iff $\;xy^{-1}\;$ is in it whenever $\;x,y\;$ are .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, take an element in $\;H_1\;$:

$$h=\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\implies h^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac b2\\0&\;\;\frac12\end{pmatrix}\notin H_1$$

Comment: Oh i haven't noticed that thankyou